# ColdFusion REGEX - to determine the file's extension

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I'm looking for a REGEX to obtain a files extension.

Given examples like:

```
modocument.doc
modocument.docx
dasddsa.pdf
kdsksdklsadklasdklads.png
ads123.jpg
```

I need a REGEX that provides the 3-4 char extension, but isn't fooled by things like:

```
asdadsasdads.jpg.png
```

And only gets PNG as seen above.

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215183/how-do-i-get-the-contents-of-a-string-minus-the-extension-in-coldfusion

Answer (score 22):

I think ListLast would do a better job for you:

```
<cfset FileExt=ListLast(YourFilename,".")>
```

Comment: This will also be much faster than using a regex.

Comment: To expand on Ben's comment - regexes don't work backwards, so they have to scan the whole string, where as ListLast will start at the end and go back, only looking at a handful of chars.

Comment: Be sure to keep in mind wether the file even has an extension.

Comment: ... because if it has no extension, `listLast()` will return the original string.